# How to choose a block of fingerprint around core region?

Tags: matlab, fingerprint

I have to design a system using fingerprint matching, the algorithm I am using asks to **first select a region around core point** and then do the manipulations. Now I have got an algorithm page 92[from this link that selects the core point](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1402/1402.4936.pdf) and it is working quite fine in terms of core point detection, but my problem is related to crop the image around the core point.
Suppose if the core point that I got is wrong or is located at the edge of the image, then when I try to crop the image the image that I got does not have the region that I require, for example let me try to explain this by an image

Suppose I have this image and I want to take its core point[image]

[image]my algorithm gives me a wrong core point (shown in red)

But this is not an issue as I am expecting design to cope up with such wrong core points detection. Now as I mentioned earlier I need to have a region around this core point the command that I am using to give me that region is:

```
[XofCenter,YofCenter]=get_core(x);
x = imcrop(x,[(XofCenter-128/2) (YofCenter-128/2) 128 128]);
```

where get_core give me the core points and imcrop gives a block of 128 cross 128 image around core point, which gives me
[image]But this is not what I want.
I want my image to include more region of fingerprint, even if that means taking my core point not as a center of my block image, some thing like this:
[image] Now Issue is how to get such thing without manually cropping the image, can somebody help me?

Comment: what you're actually asking is to "fix your core-point finding algorithm in case it is wrong". what I mean is that your problem is not with the cropping mechanism, but with the core-point algorithm which is not as robust as desired... IMO, you should try improving that part in your pipeline.

Comment: No for me to get core point wrong is not an issue, but the issue its to find a core point and then to have a region around it that is more into the fingerprint rather than into those white spaces. So what ever fixed length block size I select that block has maximum of fingerprint in it rather than the area outside fingerprint. Even if that means that my core point is not the center of my block. So the problem is with cropping mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a rather simple approach to your problem using `imfilter`:

```
% read image and set wrong core point
im = im2double(imread('fingerprint.png'));
wrong_corepoint = [64 77];
cropsize = 128;
% filter image to get accumulated values in 128X128 rects
res = imfilter(im, ones(cropsize),'replicate');
% get possible cropping area
yxmin = max([1 1],wrong_corepoint([2 1]) - cropsize + 1);
yxmax = min(size(im),wrong_corepoint([2 1]) + cropsize - 1);
% crop filterd image
res_crop = res(yxmin(1):yxmax(1),yxmin(2):yxmax(2));
% get minimum value because fingerprint is black
[v,minidx] = min(res_crop(:)); 
[rMin,cMin] = ind2sub(size(res_crop),minidx);
% convert to original image coordinates
ymin = yxmin(1) + rMin - cropsize/2 - 1;
xmin = yxmin(2) + cMin - cropsize/2 - 1;
xmin = min([xmin,size(im,2) - cropsize,wrong_corepoint(1)]);
ymin = min([ymin,size(im,1) - cropsize,wrong_corepoint(2)]);
xmin = max([xmin,1,wrong_corepoint(1) - cropsize + 1]);
ymin = max([ymin,1,wrong_corepoint(2) - cropsize + 1]);
rect = [xmin ymin cropsize cropsize];
% plot
figure;
imshow(im);
hold on
plot(wrong_corepoint(1),wrong_corepoint(2),'xr','MarkerSize',20,'LineWidth',2);
rectangle('Position',rect,'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor','g');
```

wrong core-point is marked with red X, and cropping rectangle with green:

[image]

Comment: Just one problem while running program MATLAB does not know whether the core-point selected is wrong or right. It just knows that it is a core-point!